# What is the best way to style a full width dynamic element within an element that is not full width?

Tags: html, css

I have a matrix field that the user can build their own pages in the CMS.
The page builder container is 960px wide.
There is block/ page builder item that can be created but it is full width of the screen.
Because it's dynamically created trying position absolute doesn't seem to work as it's not top or bottom of any of the elements because the element before or after could change. 
What is the tidiest way to make sure that this

```
<section class="page-builder--container">
    <div class="page-builder-item--full-width" style="background-image: url({{image.url}})">
    </div>
    <div class="page-builder-item--card">
        <h2>Card Title</h2>
        <p> I am a bunch of card content</p>
    <div>
</section>
```

Comment: You could set `max-width: 100%`. Then it'll expand to the maximum width of the parent element.

Comment: @fubar Thanks for your response but the parent is 960 and the element needs to be full width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width:100vw`. This will make that element 100% of viewport. Additionally, you may vary the value according to your requirements i.e. 90vw etc.

Learn more: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
```